# How can we detect onTabClosed(event) in Chrome Mobile Browser in Android / iOS using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, tabs, dom-events

I've been researching for 3 days straight about how to detect when a client closes a browser tab on Chrome mobile Android.

I couldn't find any working code :(

I've used Samsung Galaxy Note 10 Plus to debug through Type-C cable with Chrome PC (chrome://inspect/#devices)

and I used Android Studio's Emulator (Google Pixel),

both devices have same results, when a tab closes, nothing fires.

When I run same code on Chrome PC, it works.

I also used: requestbin.com to debug through GET Request

Here are all my research codes below. Any suggestion or idea would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <script src="lifecycle.es5.js"></script><!-- https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/page-lifecycle -->
  
  <script>
    function leftThePage(x){
        var URL = 'https://enf***********.m.pipedream.net/?test=true&x='+x+'&date='+(new Date()+"").replace(/\s/g, '');
        
        console.log("Client have left the page", x);
    
        fetch(URL, { method: "GET" });
        
        $.ajax(URL, {
            async: true,
            type: 'GET',  // http method
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("SENT1!", x);
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                console.log("ERROR1!", x);
            }
        });
        
        $.ajax(URL, {
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',  // http method
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("SENT2!", x);
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                console.log("ERROR2!", x);
            }
        });
        
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "Bam! " + x + "<br/>";
        
        alert("Bam! " + x);
    }
    
    

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) { 
        leftThePage(1);
        return null;
    });

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => { 
        leftThePage(2);
        return null;
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
        leftThePage(3);
        return null;
    };

    window.onbeforeunload = (event) => {
        leftThePage(4);
        return null;
    };



    window.addEventListener("onunload", (event) => { 
        leftThePage(5);
        return null;
    });

    window.addEventListener("onunload", function(event) { 
        leftThePage(6);
        return null;
    });

    window.onunload = function(event) {
        leftThePage(7);
        return null;
    };

    window.onunload = (event) => {
        leftThePage(8);
        return null;
    };
    
    
    
    
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
        leftThePage(9);
        //return null;
    });

    $(window).on('beforeunload', () => {
        leftThePage(10);
        //return null;
    });

    $(window).on('unload', function(){
        leftThePage(11);
        return null;
    });

    $(window).on('unload', () => {
        leftThePage(12);
        return null;
    });
    
    


    // https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api#observing-page-lifecycle-states-in-code
    const getState = () => {
      if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
        return 'hidden';
      }
      if (document.hasFocus()) {
        return 'active';
      }
      return 'passive';
    };

    // Stores the initial state using the `getState()` function (defined above).
    let state = getState();

    // Accepts a next state and, if there's been a state change, logs the
    // change to the console. It also updates the `state` value defined above.
    const logStateChange = (nextState) => {
      const prevState = state;
      if (nextState !== prevState) {
        //console.log(`State change: ${prevState} >>> ${nextState}`);
        state = nextState;
        
        if(state == "terminated"){
            leftThePage(13);
        }
      }
    };

    // These lifecycle events can all use the same listener to observe state
    // changes (they call the `getState()` function to determine the next state).
    ['pageshow', 'focus', 'blur', 'visibilitychange', 'resume'].forEach((type) => {
      window.addEventListener(type, () => logStateChange(getState()), {capture: true});
    });

    // The next two listeners, on the other hand, can determine the next
    // state from the event itself.
    window.addEventListener('freeze', () => {
      // In the freeze event, the next state is always frozen.
      logStateChange('frozen');
    }, {capture: true});

    window.addEventListener('pagehide', (event) => {
      if (event.persisted) {
        // If the event's persisted property is `true` the page is about
        // to enter the Back-Forward Cache, which is also in the frozen state.
        logStateChange('frozen');
      } else {
        // If the event's persisted property is not `true` the page is
        // about to be unloaded.
        logStateChange('terminated');
      }
    }, {capture: true});

    
    
    
    //<!-- https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/page-lifecycle -->
    lifecycle.addEventListener('statechange', function(event) {
      //console.log(event.oldState, event.newState);
      
      if(event.newState == "terminated"){
        leftThePage(14);
      }
    });
    
    </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test onCloseTab()</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?